# i can't use unity WWW request to Recive Data From My admin control panel

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, http

i am using WWW unity Request to receive json data from admin panel
put i've got this error
401 unauthorized
because the admin panel have a user name and password so i can't access it
how can i put my credential in the WWW Unity Request to Access this page ?

this is part of code

[image: 1]

Comment: By setting the authorize header In the request to the server. https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/

Comment: thanks it helped me and i used the wwwForm in unity and add Authorization to header :)